# Android Studio giving 2 errors

Tags: java, android

I am continuously getting the errors `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` and `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 37: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030004 a=-1}`. I tried to make a simple login app, but whenever I try to run it (on my smart phone , not the emulator), I get these errors. I use a 28 api level phone, but the sdk api level is 30. Please answer this question.

**Logcat :**

```
2020-11-17 08:40:04.921 10611-10611/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tanav.androidapp, PID: 10611
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tanav.androidapp/com.tanav.androidapp.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3179)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3314)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2018)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7134)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:536)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:656)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:775)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:908)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:869)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:521)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:467)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2792)
        at com.tanav.androidapp.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7278)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7269)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3314)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2018)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7134)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:536)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 37: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030004 a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:731)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5324)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:667)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:236)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:232)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:656) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:775) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:908) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:869) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:521) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:467) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2792) 
        at com.tanav.androidapp.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:17) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7278) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7269) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3159) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3314) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2018) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7134) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:536) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
```

**LoginActivity.java :**

```
package com.tanav.androidapp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        getActionBar().hide();
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void checkLogin(View view){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        EditText un = findViewById(R.id.Username);
        EditText pd = findViewById(R.id.Password);
        String username = un.getText().toString();
        String password = pd.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Checking Username and Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if ((username.equals("TanavB123"))&&(password.equals("ABCtanav2477"))){
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainPageActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            TextView errMsg = findViewById(R.id.ErrorMessage);
            errMsg.setText("Username or Password incorrect!");
            pd.setText("");
        }
    }
```

**MainPageActivity.java :**

```
package com.tanav.androidapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainPageActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
        getActionBar().hide();
    }
    public void goBack(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainPageActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**activity_login.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@color/purple_500"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Login Page"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Password"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="241dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="text|textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
        android:background="#C6DCAD"
        android:onClick="checkLogin"
        android:text="Login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Password"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Username"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.AutoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ErrorMessage"
        android:layout_width="267dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/colorError"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.587" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_main_page.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".MainPageActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@color/purple_500"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:background="@color/purple_500"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:onClick="goBack"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_vector_test"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="303dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp"
        android:text="This is my First Android App"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar7"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.452" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tanav.androidapp">

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainPageActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle(Project:Android_app) :**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "26.+"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle(Module:Android_app) :**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tanav.androidapp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: try making the height of the toolbar "wrap_content" instead of 55dp

Comment: try putting this line    getActionBar().hide(); before setContentView();

Comment: why do you need  `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` when youuse androix appcompat?

Comment: @Raghunandan idk it came by itself. I didn't edit the gradle

Comment: Did you notice the second  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);`
in your `checkLogin()` func?

Comment: is that the problem @ʍѳђઽ૯ท

Comment: Just remove getActionBar().hide(); from your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try without this function

> getActionBar().hide();

Comment: Nothing happened even after doing that